# Multipart body is null

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart, okhttp

In my app I am setting multipart body as following.

```
File file = new File(selectedImageUri);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mpeg"), file);
MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

The above code works absolutely fine

I am doing a check on the contentType as following

```
void uploadAudio(){
    File file = new File(selectedFileUri);
    MultipartBody.Part body = null;
     if (contentType == "audio") {
       RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("audio/mpeg"), file);
       body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("", file.getName(), requestBody);
     }
}
```

On The following line I assign it the Multipart it returns null.

```
body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("", file.getName(), requestBody);
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual filename
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestFile);
```

Comment: I want to split the declaration and assignment because I want to use the variable "body" throughout the function. I will be reassigning its value throughout the function

Answer (score 0):

you can use these function to get your content type

```
 // url = file path or whatever suitable URL you want.
    public static String getMimeType(String url) {
       ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
       MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
       String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(url));
       return type;
    }
```